# mysql query of a date, between two date fields

Tags: mysql, accounting, freeradius

I'm using MySql 5.5.

I need to find a userid on a date with a particular ip address.

The fields are userid, ipaddress, startdate, enddate.

So for instance I am looking for a userid with ip address 192.168.1.1 on Sep 12 2011.

the query would be similar 
`select * from database where ipaddress='192.168.1.1' and 2011-12-09 is in(startdate and enddate);`

Any help to pointing out this logic flaw is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: `AND '2011-12-09'  BETWEEN startdate AND enddate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very clear if you want:

```
'2011-12-09' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

or:

```
'2011-12-09' = startdate AND '2011-12-09' = enddate
```

Comment: note that `between` does a `<=`/`>=`-comparision, so doing `=` on start- and enddate might not give the exact same result in every case.

Comment: Apologies, I want the first one ''2011-12-09' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate'

Answer (score 1):

the obvious solution would be like:

```
  [...]
AND
  startdate <= '2011-12-09'
AND
  enddate >= '2011-12-09'
```

but theres a shortcut [using `BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) so you can simply write:

```
  [...]
AND
  '2011-12-09' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

*note:* `BETWEEN` also works for numbers, strings and other stuff, and it's possible to negate it by writing `NOT BETWEEN` - quite useful sometimes.

Comment: thanks for the hint, ypercube - i'm not a native english speaker and so this is what happens if you're too lazy to look up a word... but now it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a start and end date, maybe something along the line of:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ipaddress = '192.168.1.1' AND '2011-12-09' >= startdate AND '2001-12-09' <= enddate;
```

Or as pointed out by ypercube you can use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ipaddress = '192.168.1.1' AND '2011-12-09' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;
```

Comment: formatting the querys would make this much easier to read, having to scroll horizontally is annoying ;)