# mysql query datetime fields accuracy

Tags: mysql, accounting

I'm using MySql 5.5,

I am using the following query on a radius accounting table.

- query1:

  SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE framedipaddress='192.168.1.1' and '2011-09-09' BETWEEN acctstarttime AND acctstoptime;

The `acctstarttime` and `acctstoptime` fields are type `datetime`, formatted as `YEAR-MT-DY HR:MN:SC`.

Using query2 reveals my results of query1 are not always accurate, query1 sometimes will return nothing or an incorrect row.

- query2:

  SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE framedipaddress = '192.168.1.1' ORDER BY acctstarttime DESC LIMIT 0, 400;

Is there a different method to query two `datetime`, fields, or is it the database sanity/data is the issue?

Any guidance to the errors in my logic are welcome.

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097890/mysql-query-of-a-date-between-two-date-fields) for the query I have now.

Comment: What _would_ you like displayed? Your query should show all users that were logged in over midnight between 2011-09-08 and 2011-09-09.

Comment: Yes Joachim, that would be what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'2011-09-09' = '2011-09-09 00:00:00'` So you are only querying accounts that had an acctstarttime before this time AND an acctstoptime after this time.

If you're looking for accounts that were started on 2011-09-09. Then you could do

```
...
WHERE
acctstarttime >= '2011-09-09' AND acctstarttime < '2011-09-10'
```

If you're looking for accounts that were started and ended on 2011-09-09. Then do:

```
...
WHERE
acctstarttime >= '2011-09-09' AND acctstarttime < '2011-09-10' AND
acctstoptime >= '2011-09-09' AND acctstoptime < '2011-09-10' AND
```

FYI if you use `BETWEEN` it includes the bounds so it would include `2011-09-10 00:00:00`.

Comment: Ben, thank you for the examples. What do you mean "between includes the bounds"?.

Comment: BETWEEN is equivalent to `min <= x <= max` if x equals min or max it will be included so if you do `date BETWEEN '2011-09-09' AND '2011-09-10'` it will include records with a date = to midnight ('2011-09-10 00:00:00') on the 10th.

Comment: I may need to open another question for this - If I am looking for a particular time that is equal to or between the time in the two fields, will that be different? So for instance I want 2011-09-09 01:00:00 and it falls between a start and stop time. Thanks for your time.